# Nan values from Calculation normal distribution of a data in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, gaussian, pattern-recognition

I am doing EM algorithm with Gaussian Mixture but the problem is that my data is so spare so the values are goes around with really small values near to zero.

Here is the problematic part

```
for i=1:ncomp,
  **logdenom = -log((2*pi)^(dim/2)*sqrt(abs(det(Cov(:,:,i)))));**  
  dist = mahalan(X,Mean(:,i),Cov(:,:,i));
  y(i,:) = logdenom-0.5*dist;
end
```

Asterixed line is the problem. While the calculation, it returns 'inf' values after than resulted NAN values. How can I deal with that problem. I calculate it without log function as well

```
for i=1:ncomp,
  dist = mahalan(X,Mean(:,i),Cov(:,:,i));
  y(i,:) = exp(-0.5*dist)/sqrt((2*pi)^dim*det(Cov(:,:,i))); % problem
end
```

but the problem is same and because of the values of the Cov are so small.

Answer (score 0):

one way to prevent `inf`s in this situation is to simply use

```
 logdenom = -log( eps + (2*pi)^...  )
```

I find this v useful for sparse data in maximum likelihood estimation. I have no idea whether it will be useful in EM! Basically, the zero terms become something like `+36`, so not too large, but it still allows the amplification of small probabilities for which you need `log`.